# What can I do to make the Javascript code on my site work with Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, compatibility

My site - http://wsareviews.comuf.com - doesn't work at all on firefox. It works perfectly fine on Chrome and Safari and mostly on IE 10. Apparently its something to do with the alignIcons method that uses the event thing.

http://wsareviews.comuf.com/scripts.js

Should I use jQuery? If so, can I use jQuery to get the mouse positions and put it back into Javascript? I have no experience with jQuery at all by the way. Its for a school project and I would like it to work in as many browsers as possible except the old IEs.

Edit: so far I'm using JS for getting mouse positions and thats it. I just want a way to use jQuery to get the mouse positions and give it to the javascript code that I've already written. If you go to the link above with the js file and ctrl+f "function alignIcons(e)" you'll find the method that uses the mouse positions.

Comment: yes jquery will handle the crossbrowser issue for you, its capable of handling the events your concern about.

Comment: If you want help here, you will probably need to be a lot more specific.  Describe one specific thing that doesn't work in Firefox (exact steps to reproduce the problem) and post the particular code for that function.  Properly written javascript can be made to work in Firefox.

Comment: FYI, I can't access the link to the .js file you posted.

Comment: really, what does it say? btw I've updated my post. I can access the file on a device on different browsers and different devices.

Comment: you can see the js here from a dropbox public link. http://db.tt/Frro9e1N

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access properties of an event object that does not exist.

You are calling the function manually two places, and thus doesn't create an event:

```
function imageLoaded() {
    imageLoadCount++;
    if (imageLoadCount == numberOfImagesToLoad) {
        alignIcons();
        document.onmousemove = alignIcons;
        cancelLoadingFadeIn = true;
        setTimeout(hideSpinners, 500);
    }
}

function fadeIn() {
    document.getElementById("iconDiv").style.opacity = parseFloat(document.getElementById("iconDiv").style.opacity, 10) + 0.01;
    if (parseFloat(document.getElementById("iconDiv").style.opacity, 10) < 1.0) {
        setTimeout(fadeIn, 1000 / 60);
    } else {
        alignIcons();
    }
}
```

You should check if window.event returned anything `if (!(e && e.clientX))`. It seems like Chrome just semi-ignores it (it throws an error), but continues.

```
function alignIcons(e) {
    document.getElementById("iconDiv").style.height = window.innerHeight - 15 + "px";
    iconWindowWidth = document.getElementById("iconDiv").offsetWidth;
    iconWindowHeight = document.getElementById("iconDiv").offsetHeight;

    if (!e) {
        e = window.event;
        if (!(e && e.clientX)) {
            e = {
                clientX: iconWindowWidth / 2,
                clientY: iconWindowHeight / 2
            };
        }
    }

    mouseX = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft;
    mouseY = e.clientY + document.body.scrollLeft;
    alignPopupToCentre();
    setXPositions();
    setYPositions();
    setOpacities();
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but the `if (!(e && e.clientX))` doesn't seem to change anything. I'm trying to fix it on firefox btw not chrome, which works perfectly fine.

Comment: I know, Firefox stops on line 181, which states that `e is undefined`, which makes sense. Are you checking the log, does it raise any other error when changing that code?

Comment: nah i get the same [17:59:07.824] TypeError: e is undefined ... line 183. How do I deal with this error? I'm not sure what you're saying I should do.

Comment: @DylanThepiguy Yes you are right, I didn't think about that. See the change made in my post. I tested it on your site, and it seems to work.

Comment: Oh thats an interesting way of creating variable properties. Thank you so much this is awesome!